# When does the cohomological Atiyah–Hirzebruch–Leray–Serre spectral sequence converge?

Tags: algebraic-topology, convergence-divergence, homology-cohomology, spectral-sequences

Given a Serre fibration $F \to E \to B$ of spaces homotopy equivalent to CW complexes, with $B$ simply-connected, and a generalized homology theory $h_*$ with respect to which the fibration is orientable, there is a right-half-plane spectral sequence $(E^r,d^r)$ with second page
$$E^2_{p,q} = H_p\big(B;h_q(F)\big)$$
and converging to $h_*(E)$, first mentioned in Atiyah and Hirzebruch's seminal paper on complex K-theory but apparently folklore since work of G. W.  Whitehead.

Likewise, given a generalized cohomology theory $h^*$, there is $(E_r,d_r)$ with 
$$E^{p,q}_2 = H^p\big(B;h^q(F)\big)$$
which converges to $h^*(E)$ if $B$ is a finite CW complex. The more careful descriptions I've read of this sequence seem to concur that *in full generality, convergence does not hold*. It seems there are (at least)  two potential pitfalls:

1. The sequence may converge to something other than $h^*(E)$.
2. The sequence may fail to converge at all.

**Under what conditions does the cohomological sequence converge to $h^*(E)$?**